How to convert to Date format like 'January 2024' in T-SQL?
I am trying to convert datetime to a format like 'January 2024'.
I was able to convert format from datetime to date by using:
Convert(date, [ProcessingDate]).

Which I have the result as '2024-01-01'
How do I convert this into 'January 2024' in T-SQL?
The reason I am trying to create this format is that I need to concatenate with other varchar/text in T-SQL to be used in a drop down menu in PowerBI presentation layer.
For example:
I am trying to create drop down menu like this:
...
April 2014 

May 2024

Current = June 2014

So, I am trying to concatenate with 'Current = '
Bottom one is what I have so far in PowerBI (May 2024 as latest/current month).


Date/time formatting is a presentation-layer concern and should not take place in SQL. While we can give you an answer to your question, we'd like to first know why you want todo this, just-in-case you're making a bigger mistake.

@Dai  I have updated my original question.

"I need to concatenate with other varchar/text to be used in a drop down menu in PowerBI presentation layer." - You're meant to do that in PowerBI, though.

@Dai I am trying to join with other tables for same output like "Current = June 2024". So, I am trying to do all in SQL first before bringing data to PowerBI.

This is actually fairly easy if you haven't already found the answer.
FORMAT(Convert(date, [ProcessingDate]), 'MMMMMMMMM yyyy');
You may preferably want to remove the SQL Server-specific syntax and use:
FORMAT(CAST([ProcessingDate] as DATE), 'MMMMMMMMM yyyy');
Check out this stackoverflow article post about CAST vs CONVERT
That is the most specific answer I can come up with. You can see that it would be easy to also specify a myriad of other common formatting styles between the single quotes of the format specifier. I would also suggest using the complete FORMAT function parameters and adding the language designator like so:
FORMAT(CAST([ProcessingDate] as DATE), 'MMMMMMMMM yyyy', 'en-US');
